# Changing SessionScoped to ViewScoped?

Tags: jsf, view-scope, session-scope

I'm new to jsf, beans and everything but I need to change a sessionscoped bean to viewscoped in a finished project.

Where do I start? Appearently changing "SessionScoped" to "ViewScoped" doesnt work :).

Comment: Well, where is the bean defined as session-scoped? And what exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: First of all, are you in JSF 2? Describe your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "Sessionscoped" to "ViewScoped" should work. But the only issue is which ever thing you have manipulated over sessions will be refreshed or vanished on each view of the page.